# How does a x86-type CPU know it is communicating with the right Linux IO device?

Tags: linux, cpu-architecture

How does the x86-type (32 or 64 bits) CPU knows it is communicating with the right Linux IO device?

For example, if I have a SCSI storage device plugged into a PCI bus. How is the CPU able to detect and communicate the right commands with this device? Knowing this hardware answer will help with software programming.

Comment: The device tree tells kernel which driver to use, the driver knows how to talk to the device.

Comment: Does this mean the CPU communicate with the device driver through the IO port of the IO device?

Comment: CPU uses driver to communicate with the device. The device tree is a file that tells the kernel "what hardware we have", then the kernel call the driver's "probe" function to verify the existence of actual hardware, if "probe" is success the kernel calls the driver for read/write/control tasks to be done and driver will do them. So only the driver knows how to "actually" talk to hardware.

Comment: For example a computer has an LED. Device tells the kernel there's an LED connected to a certain GPIO. Then kernel would load the GPIO LED driver and expose the LED to sysfs. When the user attempts to turn on the LED by writing a 1 to that sysfs node, the "turn it on" function in the driver is called, which knows how to turn it on. However LED can also be controlled by I2C or PWM or other methods, so different drivers are needed, but the kernel just call the same function but provided by different drivers.

Comment: Device drivers in Linux kernel is actually highly object-oriented, although written in C. Drivers of similar devices share the same "interface" (functionally similar to the one in C++ which is a purely virtual class, but implemented in a different way, but is still a purely abstract interface that states "whoever implements this interface would be able to do those").

Comment: Thanks for giving me a good starting point. You should put your comments as an answer in order for me to check it as a good answer.